# Are lists ensured to be processed in order by a for loop?

Tags: flutter, dart

In a Flutter application, is the order of a list always ensured?

```dart
List<MyClass> myObjects;
// ... many add operations
int i = 0;
for(MyClass myObject in myObjects) {
  assert(myObject == myObjects[i]); // will it always go through?
  i++;
}
```

If not, what is the most efficient way to ensure a list is maintained and processed in the right order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `for-in` in Dart works on [`Iterable`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable-class.html) objects. (It is not like `for-in` in JavaScript which iterates over object *properties*, which could be in some indeterminate order.)

From the [`List` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List-class.html):

> Lists are `Iterable`. Iteration occurs over values in index order.